# Reverse torque by an alternator

Tags: electromagnetism

We know that alternator require torque input to produce electricity, but then why the alternator gives a negative torque when the current required by the load increases. There is a similar question but that has no answer.

Comment: Have you a link for the similar question?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/254600/negative-torque-by-an-alternator-during-sudden-change-of-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the alternator to produce a greater output of electrical energy you must provide more work input.
You can think of it in terms of Lenz's law which states the the direction of the induced current is always such as to oppose the motion producing it.

So you make the coil in the alternator rotate which induces an emf in the coil (Faraday) and with a complete circuit and a load a current flows in such a direction as to oppose the rotation of the coil.
Thus work has to be done to rotate the coil.

As the power output from the alternator is increased so the current output from the alternator also increases which in turn means that the opposition to the coil rotating increases (Lenz) which is your increased torque opposing the motion.

So rotating the coil is harder and more work per second has to be done by the device turning the coil to produce a greater output of electrical energy.